# Jelastic Poor Performance and Poor Support Issue

Tags: jelastic

Please explain me how containers are sharing hardware node resources between each other?
I feel my node is lack of CPU resources.
Even though I set maximum for cloudlets limit.
I have no real load on my node, but last month it very often stops responding for short periods and then restores with no actual reasons in logs.

I also feel my provider has poor experience with Jelastic administration.
Instead of looking for real reason why hardware node is overloaded, they just turn it off for a while and then turn it on.
See my screenshots. [Zero CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO7Rg.png) [Zero CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlFYp.png)

Is it possible for hosting provider to "oversell" hardware node?
I am looking for support from Jelastic team here.

Comment: what is inside of your environment? I mean what kind of application you host? It looks like your application does not utilize all available resources.

Comment: Node 1: Apache + PH  
Node 2: MySQL  
  
now migrating to nginx  + php-fpm + memcached

Answer (score 1):

I know that you requested a reply from Jelastic in particular, but I suppose that it might help to get some insight from a hosting provider as well.

> Is it possible for hosting provider to "oversell" hardware node?

The Jelastic platform itself does not have any limitations on this. The platform ensures that containers are distributed to the least loaded hardware nodes, but obviously if a hosting provider does not supply sufficient infrastructure / keep adding more, that distribution is worthless (i.e. all hardware is overloaded).

> I feel my node is lack of CPU resources.

From those graphs it looks like you're hitting approx. 2GHz CPU, which for a LAMP application (right?) seems to be quite high. Are you sure that your bottleneck is CPU? If yes, how did you reach that conclusion / test that assertion?

> I also feel my provider has poor experience with Jelastic administration.

Most of all, if you feel that your current Jelastic provider is not servicing your needs, did you consider moving to another one? The Jelastic ecosystem has over 30 different hosting providers. You can move your environment to another provider easily with the [Export/Import feature](https://docs.jelastic.com/environment-export-import) and the ratings on the [Jelastic Cloud Union site](https://jelastic.cloud/) can help you to identify a good quality one in your preferred location.

Comment: Thank you!
I am glad to read answer from Jelastic guru.
Your answers helped me very much while studying Jelastic.
What I did before I started to blame on provider:

Comment: - A lot of free memory on Apache node.
- MySQL node is Idle, checked table_locks_waited, slow queries etc.

I didn't test network and disk performance yet.

And finally when I started to monitor with screenshots my provider confirmed they had overload on hardware nodes.
First they moved my node to "not so loaded" hardware node.
But it didn't helped and today I had next server down alarm.
It was very long this time - for 30 minutes.
I was shocked with their answer - "We found no better solution than shut server down for a while."

Comment: Does Jelastic allow many providers in one country? I have to use local provider due to law restriction to keep user personal data on local servers.

Comment: To clarify, they stopped your node for a while, or the whole hardware node? Either way it sounds an interesting approach...

Comment: Yes there are multiple countries with multiple providers. Which country?

Comment: If I read support man reply correctly it was h/w node shut down.
Their support team use different names for same things: master-node, host-node, super-node...
Country - Russia.

Comment: We have only one partner in Russia. For now, we have requested the information about your experience with your local provider and will check this situation. As far as we can see - hardnodes of this provider have uptime more than 15days. We can find more information if you provide us with the details about your account (registered email or userID). Feel free to contact us with this link https://jelastic.com/contact/?_ga=1.98115359.1817610306.1473660520

Comment: > `And finally when I started to monitor with screenshots`

What did you see when the app did not work properly? what kind of error did you get? 

> `We found no better solution than shut server down for a while.`

This sounds weird... We will find out why they did it... 

>  `I have to use local provider due to law restriction to keep user personal data on local servers`

You can consider [Jelastic private cloud option](https://jelastic.com/virtual-private-cloud/), if your project consumes enough resources it could be a good option.